# Development: Kinect Issue "Error: NuiImageStreamOpen -2097086449"

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk, kinect.toolbox, kinect-interaction

**Greetings,**

I am developing an app in C++ using Kinect 360. I am having a problem in runtime with KinectGrabber which doesn't initialize the camera as I hoped for in runtime. When debugging it, I found that it gets an error in "MSFTKinectGrabber::Init" when testing the value of "hr". This test interrupts the program dutifully, but I don't know why.

**My setup:**

- I have installed Kinect v1.8 SDK's, then v1.8 Development Kit and finally v1.8 Runtime.
- The compiler is VStudio 2010;
- This app was developed by a colleague of mine and was running before in another computer (Laptop - windows 8);
- I am using a new desktop (Windows 10);
- Tried multiple USB entries (2.0 and 3.0) and Kinect is working in the demos of the "Developer Toolkit Browser v1.8.0 (kinect for Windows);
- Checked drivers of Kinect in Device Manager and updated them (either way, Kinect Runtime adds an extra driver feature and updates them too);

**This is the place where all seems to go wrong**, when the program enters the IF statement (@"MSFTKinectGrabber::Init"):

```
    hr = m_NuiSensor->NuiImageStreamOpen(NUI_IMAGE_TYPE_DEPTH, NUI_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_640x480,
                            depthFlags, 2, m_NextDepthFrameEvent, &m_pDepthStreamHandle);
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
    {
        std::cout << "Error: NuiImageStreamOpen " <<  hr << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
```

**Below I have the whole codes regarding:**

- My **main**, not the core of the problem I think, jsut to show how I start the program;
- My function "**initializeKinect**", where the statement if(!grabberMSFT.Init(&processor)) should be false if the "MSFTKinectGrabber::Init" returned true, which meant no problems;
- The function "**MSFTKinectGrabber::Init**", where the initialization and the tests for the Kinect are made.

Function: **Main**

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    processor = new KinectDataProcessor();
    MSFTKinectGrabber grabberMSFT;

    int kinect_state = initializeKinect(*processor, grabberMSFT, argc, argv);

    if(kinect_state==0){
        cloudProcessor = new CloudProcessor();
        int v=0;
        while (run){
            v++;
            HandleKeyboardEvents();
            processor->Update(); 
            if (startClassify && !continueClassify){
                continueClassify = true;
                boost::thread classificationThread(&threadClassify);
            }
        }
        grabberMSFT.DeInit();   
        processor->DeInit();
    }else{
        system("PAUSE");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Function: **initializeKinect**

```
int initializeKinect(KinectDataProcessor & processor, MSFTKinectGrabber & grabberMSFT, int argc,char** argv){
    int nRetCode = 0;

    if (hModule != NULL)
    {
        // initialize MFC and print and error on failure
        if (!AfxWinInit(hModule, NULL, ::GetCommandLine(), 0))
        {
            // TODO: change error code to suit your needs
            _tprintf(_T("Fatal Error: MFC initialization failed\n"));
            nRetCode = 1;
        }
        else
        {

            std::cout << "Kinect Parameters: " << std::endl;
            std::cout << "1 - MinDepth (float)  - minimum allowed is '0.0f'" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "2 - MaxDepth (float)  - maximum allowed is '4.0f'" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "3 - NearMode (int)    - '0' for true, '1' for false" << std::endl;

            float minDepth = MIN_DEPTH;//float (atof(argv[1]));
            float maxDepth = MAX_DEPTH;//float (atof(argv[2]));

            std::cout << "[MinDepth, MaxDepth] = [" << minDepth << ", " << maxDepth << "]" << std::endl;

            bool nearModeActive = true;
            std::cout << "Near mode selected\n";

            //KinectDataProcessor processor;
            if(!processor.Init(KinectProcessor::GrabberType::MSFT))
            {
                processor.DeInit();
                run = false;
                return -1;
            }


            processor.SetDepthParameters(minDepth, maxDepth, nearModeActive);

            //MSFTKinectGrabber grabberMSFT;

            if (!grabberMSFT.Init(&processor)){
                    grabberMSFT.DeInit();
                    processor.DeInit();
                    run = false;

                    return -1;
            }

            cout<<"Ready to run"<<endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO: change error code to suit your needs
        _tprintf(_T("Fatal Error: GetModuleHandle failed\n"));
        nRetCode = 1;
    }

    return nRetCode;

}
```

Function: **MSFTKinectGrabber::Init**

```
bool MSFTKinectGrabber::Init(KinectProcessor * kinectProcessor)
{
    m_KinectProcessor = kinectProcessor;

    //get NuiSensor obj
    HRESULT hr = NuiCreateSensorByIndex(0, &m_NuiSensor);
    if ( FAILED(hr) )
    {
        std::cout << "Error: NuiCreateSensorByIndex " << hr << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    m_DeviceID = m_NuiSensor->NuiDeviceConnectionId();

    hr = m_NuiSensor->NuiInitialize( NUI_INITIALIZE_FLAG_USES_COLOR | NUI_INITIALIZE_FLAG_USES_DEPTH );
    if( FAILED(hr) )
    {
        std::cout << "Error: NuiInitialize " << hr << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    //Create color and depth events
    m_NextColorFrameEvent = CreateEvent( NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL );
    m_NextDepthFrameEvent = CreateEvent( NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL );

    //open video streams
    hr = m_NuiSensor->NuiImageStreamOpen(NUI_IMAGE_TYPE_COLOR, NUI_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_640x480, 0, 2, m_NextColorFrameEvent, &m_pColorStreamHandle);
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
    {
        std::cout << "Error: NuiImageStreamOpen " <<  hr << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    DWORD depthFlags = NULL;
    if(kinectProcessor->IsMSFTNearMode())
        depthFlags = NUI_IMAGE_STREAM_FLAG_ENABLE_NEAR_MODE;

    hr = m_NuiSensor->NuiImageStreamOpen(NUI_IMAGE_TYPE_DEPTH, NUI_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_640x480, depthFlags, 2, m_NextDepthFrameEvent, &m_pDepthStreamHandle);
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
    {
        std::cout << "Error: NuiImageStreamOpen " <<  hr << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    // Start the NUI processing thread
    m_ProcessThreadStopEvent = CreateEvent( NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL );
    m_ProcessThread = CreateThread( NULL, 0, ProcessThread, this, 0, NULL );

    return true;
}
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

**Quick answer:**

If your Kinect has "XBOX360" written on its front side than you cannot use the Near Mode and you need to change your nearModeActive from true to false.

---

**More details:**

I believe the issue is that you are trying to use the Near Mode with regular Kinect. In your initializeKinect the following is hardcoded:

```
bool nearModeActive = true;
std::cout << "Near mode selected\n";
```

and then

```
processor.SetDepthParameters(minDepth, maxDepth, nearModeActive);
```

The MSFTKinectGrabber::Init then tries to open the depth stream in near mode, because of the following:

```
if(kinectProcessor->IsMSFTNearMode())
    depthFlags = NUI_IMAGE_STREAM_FLAG_ENABLE_NEAR_MODE;
```

The problem is: regular XBOX Kinect does not support this feature. Only Kinect for Windows does. In fact, that is the only real difference between them. The Kinect for Windows is [much more expensive](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B006UIS53K). You can read more about the Near Mode [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kinectforwindows/2012/01/20/near-mode-what-it-is-and-isnt/).